# Can a previously used Aron Kodesh be used a Sefarim closet?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, sefer-torah, ark-aron-kodesh, kedusha-holiness

Someone in my neighborhood wants to donate a used Aron Kodesh to a shul. There is a shul in my neighborhood that I thought could use it, but they have one, already. But, I'm wondering if they would be allowed to use it as a *Sefarim* closet? Or is this a case (no pun, intended) of *moridin bakodesh* (descending in holiness)?

I checked Talmud Megillah 26b which lists *tashmishei kodesh* and *tashmishei mitzvah*. They mention תיק של ס"ת, which I don't think is the same as an *Aron*. So, I'm uncertain what category that would be considered.

Comment: Doesn’t Megillah mention a *teivah*? I always understood that to be equivalent to an *aron*.

Comment: @JoelK If I'm not mistaken, the term *teiva* means the table used for reading the Torah. In contrast, the *amud* is the table used for the shat"z's prayer.

Comment: *Tik* might very well mean "aron" in this case, as it seems unlikely (from other discussions on this site) that a Torah case of the Sephardi style was already in existence in the times of Chaza"l

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I'm inclined to disagree. I think the term "aron" was already in use in the Talmud. Certainly, we see the term used in Tanac"h. Why wouldn't the Gemara use that term, here, directly, instead of another term if they meant "aron"?

Comment: Take a look at OC 153:2 where the mechaner defines a teivah as היכל שמניחין בו ספר תורה או לוח שמעמידין עליו ספר תורה. Sounds like an Aron Kodesh to me.

Comment: The shatz is yoreid lifnei hateivah because that’s where his amud is located - in front of the aron.

Comment: @JoelK You are correct in that in the Talmud, *teiva* meant the ark, itself. Of interest, perhaps, see the supplement to this article: https://www.beureihatefila.com/files/2007-12-14_Tefila_Newsletter.pdf that mentions the change in terminology over time. Interesting info.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kitzur Yalkut Yosef 1:166:4-5](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulkhan_Aruch_Yalkut_Yosef.1.166.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (A Sefardi Posek):

- There are those that say you can put Gemarot and Halachic works in an old Aron Kodesh, since this was implicitly agreed upon from the outset.
- One can rely on the Taz and others who are lenient and permit this, since it is better than burying it.

The [Mishna Berurah (154:8, s"k 37)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&pgnum=69) says that it appears from the wording of the Trumat Hadeshen (the source of this leniency) that it is better to explicitly allow the use of the Aron Kodesh for other purposes when donating or buying it for the synagogue.

The Mishna Berurah also adds that this leniency (of not having to explicitly  permit the use of the Aron for other purposes) only applies to an Aron Kodesh bought for a synagogue, it does not apply to an Aron used to store a Sefer Torah in a private residence.

Comment: I don't understand the 1st item. How was there an implicit agreement? Do you mean that when the Aron was built, it includes placing books as well as Sifrei Torah?

Comment: @DanF: Yes. It was a loose translation of "The heart of Bet Din made a condition [to include the Talmud and Halachic Works] from the beginning"

Comment: @DanF: If you're looking for a practical solution, you can sell the Aron and use the money for Tashmishei Kedusha. The Aron then loses its holiness (See paragraph 6 in the Yalkut Yosef). Again, this is for Sefardim, I'm not sure what Ashkenazim would say, CYLOR

Comment: OK, I viewed the source. I still don't understand what he means by the "heart of Bet Din". What does this have to do with a Bet Din? 2nd comment is an interesting work-around. In this case, though, it's not practical. The donor specifically wants to donate this to a shul. It's now a question of my finding a shul that can use it in some way.

Comment: Considering that normal practice is not to use old aron kodesh for other sefarim, lev bes din is NOT masna as mentioned already in Mishna Berurah in siman 154 #36.

Comment: @user6591 Please explain the concept of "Lev Bet Din". I'm completely lost as to what this means, here. I understand the literal translation of the term; I just don't understand what it means in this context.

Comment: @DanF b.d. here just means the people in charge of communal needs. Like when nobody circumcised a child and b.d. steps in...it means communal leaders. In this situation, a stipulation could have been made before using this aron (or any tashmishei kedusha) to allow mundane use. Who was in charge to make that stipulation? The pseudo b.d. Did they? Unless we know what they did or did not stipulate, we can assume there was a stipulation but only to include uses that this item is normally used for afterwards. So if a community commonly uses old aron kodesh for bookshelves, it is fine.

Comment: @user6591 Goodness! In my case, now, I have no clue as to what a community does with a used Aron. All I know is that someone has this in his home and wants to donate it and I won the "lottery" but I can't locate a shul that needs it! Go figure why even a donation has to be so complicated!

Comment: @DanF enjoy your white elephant:)